# External Website Post to EE Entries

Tags: safecracker, api, rest

I have never worked with another Third Party System before that prefers to push data to me than provide an API to just pull that data down as needed - but they have their reasons they say!

On that basis they say they typically use a basic method of the client providing a form to which they post the data each time. Now this means they post direct to the form submission URL - so my initial thought was channel forms - but then i remembered XSS and how this will prevent it.
So is there a way to disable XSS token checks specifically for a single form, or just site wide (which i would prefer to avoid).

If not - i will use  addon to create a REST api on the EE end and get them to submit to that. Does anyone have any experience with such a addon as:
http://docs.reinos.nl/webservice/#introduction

Thanks, N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the POST submission would be rejected not due to [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), but [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). It's not an appropriate API to use for continuous submission from an external source.

I haven't used Reinos' add-on, but depending on the third-party's flexibility, their aptitude, and your custom field requirements, it's possible that your needs would be covered by the native [Metaweblog API](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/add-ons/metaweblog_api/index.html). You would install it and configure a specific endpoint for them to use. They would send a Metaweblog API compatible request to that URL, which would be exempted from CSRF protection, and use its own authentication.

Comment: Really good point. I did not think to try that. Trying out Reinos add-on and it seems very good indeed so far. But will try this too. Thanks Mr Jones